# Django 3.X admin showing all models in a new navbar

Tags: python, django

I run my web application on pythonanywhere and main admin page works fine, but others show my models on left side, can't find reason for this. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1) [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/),

> The admin now has a sidebar on larger screens for easier navigation.
> It is enabled by default but can be disabled by using a custom
> **AdminSite** and setting [**`AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar)
> to `False`.

Comment: in which file do you set enable_nav_sidebar to False?

Comment: It depends on where your custom [**`AdminSite`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects) resides.